# a good javascript/jquery color scheme generator (like kuler)

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-scheme, color-picker

I'm looking for a color picker and color scheme generator based on javascript-html (preferably as a jQuery plugin).

The picker should be able to suggest seconday and tertiary colors based on a selected primary color and a selected scheme rule (triads, monocomatic, complimentary, etc..).

It should works something like [this](http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor) 
It shouldn't be as copmprehensive as kuler though, and not take up more space than the colorpicker from [here](http://eyecon.ro/colorpicker)

I've been searching already of course, and couldn't find any. I'll be ready to get one developed, but would like to hear any suggestions for existing solutions or solutions that provide some of the functionality I'm looking for here (to fork from)..

Comment: You might also want to try http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this more of a programmer question, at graphicdesign I can't even tag it appropriately (jquery and javascript aren't available tags), and it suggest color-theory and color-profiling, which suggests the site is intended at a different audience than what I'm trying to reach.

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem. Did you find any? Thanks in advance.

Comment: These might be useful: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/  ,    http://www.checkman.io/please/

Answer (score 4):

Check this: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/#meth_darken.

Color selection is a bit wonky but there are several color rules in place to spit out some combinations.